# Call method thru JNI with char[] parameter

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a Java method from my native code, but it fails. I cannot call the method with a const string (i.e. "string" as a parameter nor by the following way.
If I remove the char[] parameter from the method and call it from the native only with the int parameter it's work. So the problem is the char[] parameter.

I have the Java class Stats:

```
public class Stats {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mStats;

    public Stats() {
        mStats = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public void put(char[] key, int value) {
        mStats.put(new String(key), value);
    }

}
```

And a native function

```
void Java_com_..._testObject(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis,
        jobject jStatsObj) {
    jclass jstatistics_class = env->GetObjectClass(jStatsObj);
    jmethodID jput_method = env->GetMethodID(jstatistics_class, "put", "(C[I)V");
    char s[]={"hello"};
    env->CallIntMethod(jStatsObj, jput_method, s, 3);
}
```

Comment: do you get an exception? any possible hint as to what the problem could be? do you get a blue screen of death when the code runs? i'm sure this is a quick fix for anyone experienced with JNI and you might receive an answer, but you should try to make your question as easy as possible to answer for the rest of us.

Comment: A C char is not the same as a Java char, in addition a C array is also not the same as a Java array. You will need to do much conversion work to create a Java char array from a C char array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the method signature wrong.

`(C[I)V` means `void method(char, int[])`

You need `([CI)V`.

Source: [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html).

Comment: @Bush Never guess at JNI method signature strings. Use the output of javap -s.